# 'stream "messagestream" has not been initialized' error

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a messaging system for my app, which uses the stream "messageStream", which I use first here:

```
class _chatscreenstate extends State<chatscreen> {
  late String chatroomId = ' ';
  late String messageId = '';
  late String myName;
  late String myProfilePic = "";
  late Stream<QuerySnapshot> messageStream;
  TextEditingController messageTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
```

Just as a sidenote, none of the code I have posted here gives any errors, the errors occur only when the program is run and tries to build the stream.
I also use the messagestream in this widget:

```
  Widget chatmessages() {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: messageStream,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? ListView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 70, top: 16),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                    return chatMessageTile(
                        ds["message"], username.value == ds["sendbyme"]);
                  })
              : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        });
  }
```

Which takes another widget "chatMessageTile" which contains the data in the textbubbles which will be used to build the list. Here is where I am getting the data:

```
getAndSendMessages() async {
    messageStream = await database().getChatRoomMessages(chatroomId);
  }

  doThisOnLaunch() async {
    await getMyInfoFromSharedPreference();
    getAndSendMessages();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    doThisOnLaunch();
    super.initState();
  }
```

This concludes all the places that I've used messageStream in my code.

When I tried running it, I get the error:

```
The following LateError was thrown building chatscreen(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedTheme,
_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#d42c2]], state: _chatscreenstate#c4a8c):
LateInitializationError: Field 'messageStream' has not been initialized.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  chatscreen
  chatscreen:file:///Users/jshen/Documents/GitHub/TwoCents/twocents_app/lib/josh/twocentsmessaging/messagehome.dart:331:63

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _chatscreenstate.messageStream (package:twocents_app/josh/twocentsmessaging/Chatscreen.dart)
#1      _chatscreenstate.chatmessages (package:twocents_app/josh/twocentsmessaging/Chatscreen.dart:120:17)
#2      _chatscreenstate.build (package:twocents_app/josh/twocentsmessaging/Chatscreen.dart:180:26)
#3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4992:27)
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4878:15)
#5      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5050:11)
#6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
#7      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4859:5)
#8      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5041:11)
#9      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4853:5)
...     Normal element mounting (24 frames)
#33     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
#34     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6435:36)
#35     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6447:32)
...     Normal element mounting (175 frames)
#210    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
#211    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6435:36)
#212    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3592:18)
#213    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5964:32)
#214    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6460:17)
#215    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3570:15)
#216    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
#217    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5050:11)
#218    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
#219    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5082:5)
#220    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3570:15)
#221    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
#222    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
#223    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5228:5)
#224    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3570:15)
#225    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
#226    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
#227    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5228:5)
#228    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:107:11)
#229    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3570:15)
#230    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6307:14)
#231    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3570:15)
#232    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
#233    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5050:11)
#234    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
#235    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5082:5)
#236    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3570:15)
#237    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6307:14)
#238    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3570:15)
#239    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6307:14)
#240    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3570:15)
#241    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
#242    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
#243    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5228:5)
#244    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3570:15)
#245    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
#246    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5050:11)
#247    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
#248    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2667:19)
#249    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:882:21)
#250    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:378:5)
#251    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1175:15)
#252    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1104:9)
#253    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1015:5)
#254    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:148:13)
#255    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:318:5)
#256    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>'
#0      _chatscreenstate.getAndSendMessages (package:twocents_app/josh/twocentsmessaging/Chatscreen.dart:136:5)
#1      _chatscreenstate.doThisOnLaunch (package:twocents_app/josh/twocentsmessaging/Chatscreen.dart:141:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

And the Iphone simulator shows the red screen with yellow text saying : "Field messageStream has not been initialized". I'm not sure why since I declared the stream as "late", and nothing I've found online fixes it. Any ideas?

Comment: try removing async and await from  `getAndSendMessages`

Answer (score 0):

doThisOnLaunch is an async function, you are not awaiting its call in initState. So initState will not wait until the call to doThisOnLaunch is finished.

You can't make the initState async, so i suggest moving the initialization code to didChangeDependencies which can be async

```
  bool _isInitialized = false;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    if (!_isInitialized) {
       await doThisOnLaunch();
       _isInitialized = true;
    }
  }
```